# make Google Cloud Storage public url's only accessible to my react native app

Tags: database

I have a Node backend that uploads users' profile pictures to Google Cloud Storage, which returns a Public URL that is stored against the user doc in MongoDB. I want this URL to only be accessible from my React Native app, and nowhere else. In other words, I want it to not be public. I'm shying away from Signed URL's because I don't want the URL to expire and for the user to have to re-upload an image.

What options do I have? Is it possible to somehow add a react native app as a "member" or create a service account for the frontend?

I'm new to this so I'm not very comfortable with setting permissions on resources.

Comment: `I'm not very comfortable with setting permissions on resources` - but this is precisely what you need to do. Sounds like a good time to learn!